# TYPO3 language menu with tx_news - hide language from menu if news record is not translated

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tx-news

I want to hide a language from my language menu if a news record is not translated.

The following setup works perfectly for pages. So if a page has no translation, the "English" is not shown in the language menu on the website.

I would like to have this behaviour for not translated news records as well.

The language menu so far:

```
lib.language = COA
lib.language {
    20 = HMENU
    20 {
        special = language
        special.value = 0,1
        special.normalWhenNoLanguage = 0
        wrap =
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            noBlur = 1
            NO = 1
            NO {
                linkWrap = <li>|</li>
                stdWrap.override = Deutsch || English
                stdWrap {
                    typolink {
                        parameter.data = page:uid
                        additionalParams = &L=0 || &L=1 
                        ATagParams = hreflang="de-DE" || hreflang="en-GB"
                        addQueryString = 1
                        addQueryString.exclude = L,id,cHash,no_cache
                        addQueryString.method = GET
                        useCacheHash = 1
                        no_cache = 0
                    }
                }
            }

            ACT < .NO
            ACT.linkWrap = <li class="active">|</li>
            USERDEF1 = 1
            USERDEF1 {
                ldoNotLinkIt = 1
                stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
                stdWrap.cObject.value = 
            }

            USERDEF2 = 1
            USERDEF2 {
                doNotLinkIt = 1
                stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
                stdWrap.cObject.value = 
            }
        }
    }

    wrap = <ul id="language_menu" class="language-menu">|</ul>
}
```

My typoscript configuration:

```
  config.sys_language_mode = strict
  config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
```

LocalConfiguration.php

```
[FE][hidePagesIfNotTranslatedByDefault] = 1
```

Comment: Hi Chris, i have the same problem, could you please show your Walkthrough? The answer below is not clear to me. :)

Comment: hey, i have fetch same issue. did you get any solution for that?

Comment: same here, also the answer is not clear

Answer (score 1):

with version 8.5.0 the TYPO3 extension `news` comes with a new `DisableLanguageMenuProcessor` which will set the desired language menu items to `available => false`, if a news record has no translation:

https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/11.2/en-us/Tutorials/ExtendNews/DataProcessing/LanguageMenuProcessor.html?highlight=language

```
10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\LanguageMenuProcessor
10 {
   as = languageMenu
   addQueryString = 1
}

11 = GeorgRinger\News\DataProcessing\DisableLanguageMenuProcessor
11 {
  if.isTrue.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
  menus = languageMenu
}
```

The solution with `itemArrayProcFunc` will only work, if you build your language menu with plain `HMENU`. If you build your language menu with `LanguageMenuProcessor` you can not use `itemArrayProcFunc` as that is marked as an invalid property for that DataProcessor. I have created a forge ticket here to hook into that part in future: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/102349

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually set the USERDEF1 state. This Utility class should help: https://gist.github.com/birger-fuehne/a8a97c94ec9346d691174462ccbfcfcc